# How to separate key of json data and use it in table header [ javascript or PHP ]

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this table and I am doing hardcoded table header but I want it dynamic as per JSON data schema

**for example**, my JSON data is as below

```
[
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784208932,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -90,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784212032,
    "battery": 3660,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -89,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784215034,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -96,
    "temp": 25.75
  }
]
```

**I want to generate table header using this JSON data**

```
<thead>
    <th>adapterid</th>
    <th>rowid</th>
    <th>battery</th>
    <th>createddate</th>
    <th>gid</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>projectid</th>
    <th>rssi</th>
    <th>temp</th>
</thead>
```

Comment: `foreach key as value` doesnt work for you?

Comment: I try but it is not working i need to create < th > element from each record it generates      foreach($json as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        echo $key;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}

Comment: All the answers are for purely javascript solutions. So I got confused what you wanted, since you included `php` in the tags. Nevermind.

Comment: worked for me thanks i load the javascript function after dom created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys from an object then loop through them to form the header.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784208932,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -90,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784212032,
    "battery": 3660,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -89,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784215034,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -96,
    "temp": 25.75
  }
]
var header = Object.keys(data[0]);
var thead = document.querySelector('table thead tr');
header.forEach(function(th){
  thead.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<th>${th}</th>`)
})
```

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide an HTML page or PHP page because I tried this and I am getting errors.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
    at js.php:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at js.php:39

Comment: @harshsuthar, the error indicates that the JavaScript code is running before the dom is fully loaded. To solve the issue either you can place the JavaScript code at the bottom of the body or wrap the code with `DOMContentLoaded` described https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 0):

You need only 2 lines:

```
let Rowhead = MyTable.createTHead().insertRow(-1)
Object.keys(infoTable[0]).forEach((T,i)=>Rowhead.insertCell(i).textContent=T)
```

example:

```js
const infoTable = 
      [ { adapterid: 44835, rowid: 1573784208932, battery: 3610, createddate: "15-11-2019", gid: "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87", id: 2277491836402479600, projectid: 32107, rssi: -90, temp: 25.75 } 
      , { adapterid: 44835, rowid: 1573784212032, battery: 3660, createddate: "15-11-2019", gid: "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87", id: 2277491836402479600, projectid: 32107, rssi: -89, temp: 25.75 } 
      , { adapterid: 44835, rowid: 1573784215034, battery: 3610, createddate: "15-11-2019", gid: "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87", id: 2277491836402479600, projectid: 32107, rssi: -96, temp: 25.75 } 
      ];
const MyTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')
    , Tcols   = Object.keys(infoTable[0])
    ;
let Rowhead = MyTable.createTHead().insertRow(-1)
Tcols.forEach((T,i)=>Rowhead.insertCell(i).textContent=T)
```

```css
body  { font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
Table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: .7em; }
td    { border: 1px solid grey; padding: 2px 10px; }
thead { background-color: turquoise;}
```

```html
<table id="my-table"></table>
```

complete info:

```js
const infoTable = 
      [ { adapterid: 44835, rowid: 1573784208932, battery: 3610, createddate: "15-11-2019", gid: "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87", id: 2277491836402479600, projectid: 32107, rssi: -90, temp: 25.75 } 
      , { adapterid: 44835, rowid: 1573784212032, battery: 3660, createddate: "15-11-2019", gid: "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87", id: 2277491836402479600, projectid: 32107, rssi: -89, temp: 25.75 } 
      , { adapterid: 44835, rowid: 1573784215034, battery: 3610, createddate: "15-11-2019", gid: "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87", id: 2277491836402479600, projectid: 32107, rssi: -96, temp: 25.75 } 
      ];

const MyTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')
    , Tcols   = Object.keys(infoTable[0])
    , nbTcols = Tcols.length
    ;
for(let line of infoTable )
  {
  let nRow = MyTable.insertRow(-1)
  for (let c=0; c<nbTcols; c++)
    {
    if (line[Tcols[c]]) { nRow.insertCell(c).textContent = line[Tcols[c]] }
    else                { nRow.insertCell(c).textContent = ''             } // empty cell ?
    }
  }

let Rowhead = MyTable.createTHead().insertRow(-1)
Tcols.forEach((T,i)=>Rowhead.insertCell(i).textContent=T)
```

```css
body  { font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
Table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: .7em; }
td    { border: 1px solid grey; padding: 2px 10px; }
thead { background-color: turquoise;}
```

```html
<table id="my-table"></table>
```